# Try to display images from a directory in Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I try to display all images from a directory that is in the project.
In the views.py

```
def showimages(request):
    path='C:\\Users\Peter\PycharmProjects\displayimages\displayimages\display\static'
    img_list = os.listdir(path)

    return render(request, 'displayphotos.html', {'images':img_list})
```

In the html file

```
{% for image in images %}

    <p>{{image}}</p>
    <img src="{% static '{{image}}' %}">

{% endfor %}
```

But the display is

```
<p>DSC_5390.jpg</p>
<img src="/static/%7B%7Bimage%7D%7D">

<p>DSC_5392.jpg</p>
<img src="/static/%7B%7Bimage%7D%7D">
```

If I print them in paragraph tag, all file names are correct, but all wrong in img tag. How can I fix it?

Comment: Try `{% static image %}`. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54922092/8795073).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have an easy issue, just write

```
<img src="{% static {{image}} %}">
```

insead of

```
<img src="{% static '{{image}}' %}">
```

remove the simple quotes

Answer (score 0):

if you have the image inside you static folder than you first need to load the static folder in setting file.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
   os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]
```

and than just load the image with the correct path in your template. if you have a folder for your images than

```
<img src="{% static 'images/grad-hat.png' %}">
```

else the image name

```
<img src="{% static 'grad-hat.png' %}">
```